# Study the convergence of this improper integral

Tags: improper-integrals

$$ \int_o^\infty t^ae^{bt}dt $$ for a,b reals.

I guess I would have to separate this integral in many cases for different values of a and b.

I know that if b < 0,

$$ \int_o^\infty t^ae^{bt}dt >  \int_o^\infty {t^a}dt  $$, which diverges for any a.  The other cases are more tricky.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The last inequality is not true, since $e^{bt}<1$ for large $t$ and $b<0$.

Comment: Hint: Doesn't it look like the Gamma function...?

Comment: Another point is that $$ \int_o^\infty t^ae^{bt}dt >  \int_o^\infty {t^a}dt  $$ is not true for $b<0$.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function

Answer (score 1):

If $b>0$ then
$$\lim_{t \to +\infty} t^ae^{bt}=+\infty$$
for any $a$ and the integral diverges.
If $b<0$ then the near $0$ you have $1<e^{bt}<2$ hence the integral converges if and only if $a>-1$, since there is no problem at infinity.
For $b=0$ the integral never converges.